# Weird exception message when using CreateDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Recently it was brought to my attention an issue with one of our users. The application is failing to copy some files. The problem is when trying to create a directory on the destination drive it throws an IOException. Here is the exception details:

```
Message: Could not find file 'I:\Destination\C\Users\Alan\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable'.
Inner Exception: 
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
```

The directory being created when this exception occur is `"I:\Destination\C\Users\Alan\Downloads\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\drawable"`.

What is bothering me is the message `Could not find file` which is kinda weird since I am trying to create a directory, not a file. And even if the file/directory does not exist it should not throw such an exception as the application is trying to CREATE the directory in question. My problem is that I am unable to reproduce this issue as it is happening constantly on one of our client's machines.

So I was wondering if someone has encountered the same issue before.

Comment: My guess would be that you are playing tug of war with their AV software

Comment: This error code starts at the driver that implements the file system on the drive.  An I: drive is almost never anything "normal".  Throw in something like a network redirector or security software to make it extra undiagnosable.

Comment: Only a comment - end the directory with a \

Comment: @Blam Will try that however, the call is failing randomly. It like works for a couple of files then fails for the next 10 and so on. And this is called by a single thread, so its not a multi-threading issue

Comment: That's a very strange path.  Understanding the reasons why the content is where it is may help you understand the reasons why CreateDirectory is having trouble.

Comment: @HarryJohnston what is so strange about the path? It looks fine to me, the application in question is a backup application. The user chooses the source files to backup which in this case is the Downloads folder and then he chooses which drive/location he wants the files to be copied/compressed to and in this case the destination is `I:\Destination`

Comment: @RedSerpent: OK, that explains it.

Comment: If the problem is being reported by only one particular user, is it possible that the drive in question has an intermittent hardware fault?

Comment: @HarryJohnston yes it is only happening to a single client. And yes its possible that the drive is faulty although he said that he bought it only a couple months ago and did not have any problems with it

Comment: @HarryJohnston I only posted this because the exception looked weird and I couldn't find any explanation as to how this particular exception could be raised

Comment: In my experience, hardware problems can cause all sorts of strange error codes to bubble up to the application layer. :-)  But there are other possibilities, really there isn't any way to tell other than trial and error.